# Взаимодействие React с элементами DOM созданными не с помощью React

Tags: dom, reactjs

Не могу определиться, поможет ли построение интерфейса на `React` для следующих задач.

1. Перетаскивание `Drag and Drop` любых элементов `DOM`.
2. Клонирование любых элементов `DOM`.
3. Встраивание в любые элементы `DOM` компонентов `React` на лету (например добавление компонента к любому динамически появляющемуся на странице `DOM` елементу по определенному имени класса.).
4. Уладение любых элементов `DOM`

Речь идет как о элементах созданных с помощью `React` так и существующих элементов на странице или же добавляемых например `jQuery`

Comment: всё возможно, но зачем это нужно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reactjs` использует свой собственный виртуальный DOM. и любые изменения на странице тем же `jquery` он не увидит (также как и `jquery` не увидит что творит `react`). 
Он прекрасно справится со всеми вашими пунктами, но пересекать `react` и `jquery` ни в коем случае нельзя.